# python - No module named 'bitcoin' on Ubuntu using WSL on Windows 10

Tags: bitcoin-core, python, mastering-bitcoin, python-bitcoinlib

Which version of python should I use?
When running `pip3 install python-bitcoinlib` I get 'Requirement already satisfied'.
I run on Ubuntu using WSL in Windows 10.
I have this error:

```
>>> from bitcoin.rpc import RawProxy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Rony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bitcoin\rpc.py", line 48, in <module>
    from bitcoin.wallet import CBitcoinAddress, CBitcoinSecret
  File "C:\Users\Rony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bitcoin\wallet.py", line 33, in <module>
    import bitcoin.core.key
  File "C:\Users\Rony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bitcoin\core\key.py", line 34, in <module
>
  _ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or 'libeay32')
  File "C:\Users\Rony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\Rony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: What's the exact error it is printing when failing to import?

Comment: @Mercedes >>> from bitcoin.rpc import RawProxy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitcoin'

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python 3?

Comment: `import sys; sys.version;`

Comment: @Mercedes '3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) \n[GCC 9.4.0]'

Comment: `import bitcoin; bitcoin.__version__;`, or find an equivalent one using bpython, don't use python but bpython to explore libraries you are not familiar with.

Comment: Won't work because the bitcoin module isn't there. Your pip3 must belong in somewhere else. Is there any *conda in your system?

Comment: `which pip3; which python`

Comment: @Mercedes I made sure both are in the same place: which pip3.exe; which python.exe
/mnt/c/Users/Rony/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/pip3.exe
/mnt/c/Users/Rony/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe

Comment: @Mercedes I edited the post with the new error, it's too long for a comment.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/8846029 (via https://github.com/weex/addrgen/issues/5)

Comment: @Mercedes I need to install the C# openssl on my wsl ubuntu? If I just downloading those 2 files I get this error: _ssl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('ssl') or 'libeay32')
  File "C:\Users\Rony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\Rony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: @Mercedes I run on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Check if its already listed in `pip list`

If yes, remove it using `pip uninstall python-bitcoinlib`

Then try `pip3 install python-bitcoinlib`

Also be careful with python packages, few might be malwares with similar names: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/07/malicious-pypi-packages-caught-stealing-developer-data-and-injecting-code/

Comment: I did it and I have the same error. Maybe I should remove all python from my windows and install python 3 again...